# why I don't see any cells in my UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` and I put on it `TableView`:

[image]

I also added the `UITableViewCell` to it, checked in story board that my table view has dynamic-generated content and added an identifier "cell" to the `UITableViewCell`. I connected it with outlets to my class and I set up the inheritance from `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableDetailsPanel: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableDetailsPanel.delegate = self
}
```

Then I add my custom object to my array:

```
var items = NSMutableArray()
...
print("size of items before: \(items.count)")
items.addObject(myObject)
print("size of items after: \(items.count)")
myTableDetailsPanel.reloadData()
myTableDetailsPanel.hidden = false
```

I also have this method:

```
func tableView(myTableDetailsPanel: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableDetailsPanel.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MyDetailsCell
    let yawp:MySingleObject =  self.items[indexPath.row] as! MySingleObject
    print("hello")
    ...
```

And... my problem is that the panel appears empty, in the console I see:

```
size of items before: 0
size of items after: 1
```

but somehow I don't see `hello`. My code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never runs. Why so?

Comment: You're missing the declaration of the `myTableDetailsPanel.dataSource = self` and of course implement the `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: thanks man, that was it! please submit it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Use `var items = [MySingleObject]()` rather than `var items = NSMutableArray()` then you get rid of a lot of type casting.

Comment: @vadian yes, but if I do so, then I'm getting errors that `Value of type [MySingleObject] has no member removeAllObjects` or the same with `addObject`

Comment: `removeAllObjects()` == `removeAll()`, `addObject(..` == `append(..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to be notified about changes in the `UITableView` you have to implement the [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource), the data source provides to table-view object with the information it needs to construct and modify a table view.

So you need to implement `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and declare the `dataSource` as `self` like this:

```
myTableDetailsPanel.dataSource = self
```

I hope this help you.